# developing htmlwidgets with devtools

Tags: r, shiny, htmlwidgets

I am on a windows 10 machine. Trying to experiment with htmlwidget development.

To test things out, I have a local clone of the [sigma](https://github.com/jjallaire/sigma) package, which is the example provided in the `htmlwidgets` tutorials.

Based on [this](https://community.rstudio.com/t/testbed-for-developing-htmlwidgets-how-to-iterate-quickly/10297) post, I am lead to believe that devtools would work fine with htmlwidgets. However if I do

```r
library(devtools)
load_all()
sigma(system.file("examples/ediaspora.gexf.xml", package = "sigma"))
```

The resulting widget is blank. If I examine the html code of the output, I see that the required javascript files for sigma is not loaded.

However if I do

```r
library(devtools)
install()
library(sigma)
sigma(system.file("examples/ediaspora.gexf.xml", package = "sigma"))
```

I get the network. Examining the html of the output reveals that the required javascript files are loaded this time.

Am I supposed to be installing the package I am developing to be able to test it out? Is there a way to work around this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From reading the solution in that post, devtools works with htmlwidgets if you use one of two workarounds (just summarizing them here):

1. Use `devtools::load_all()` on the htmlwidgets package, and then `load_all()` your widget package. This would require you to have the htmlwidgets source somewhere locally. For example, clone the https://github.com/ramnathv/htmlwidgets repo to `~/htmlwidgets`, and then run `devtools::load_all("~/htmlwidgets")`.
2. Run this code to shim `system.file` for htmlwidgets, and then `load_all()` your widget package: https://gist.github.com/wch/c942335660dc6c96322f

```
shim_system_file <- function(package) {
  imports <- parent.env(asNamespace(package))
  pkgload:::unlock_environment(imports)
  imports$system.file <- pkgload:::shim_system.file
}

shim_system_file("htmlwidgets")
shim_system_file("htmltools")
```

Of the two, I'd probably use the second since it's easier, maybe place it in a `.Rprofile` to have it run at the start of every R session.

---

I've just learned there's an even easier solution though. The development versions of htmlwidgets and htmltools have `system.file` shims built-in now, so `load_all()` just works: https://github.com/ramnathv/htmlwidgets/pull/340. You can install the dev version of both like:

```
devtools::install_github("ramnathv/htmlwidgets")
```

And then just `load_all()` your widget package as usual without further workarounds.

Comment: One thing to note is that placing the code in .Rprofile doesn't seem to be sufficient for Rstudio servers since packages get unloaded and .Rprofile is not re-executed when session goes on standby. So it seems like it is necessary to manually run the code unless you restart your session